# Why is OperationCancelledException conveying different CancellationToken than the one from CTSource?

Tags: c#, async-await, ado.net

Why is the CancellationToken stored in the exception different to token provided by CancellationTokenSource?

```
[Test]
public static async Task SqlCommand_should_recognise_which_CT_triggered_its_cancellation()
{

    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);

    try
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.ConnectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync(cts.Token);
        var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand("select 1", connection);

        await Task.Delay(timeout + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        await sqlQuery.ExecuteScalarAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException cancelledEx)
    {
        //Shouldn't they be the same?
        Assert.AreEqual(cancelledEx.CancellationToken, cts.Token);
        // The below fails as well
        // Assert.IsTrue(cancelledEx.CancellationToken == cts.Token);


    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, following the source code you get to `CancellationTokenSource timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();` inside `RunExecuteReaderTds` and it's not linked to the one you provided. Not clear from the code if the one you provide actually does anything if you cancel it after it's started (it checks up-front).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the CancellationToken stored in the exception different to token provided by CancellationTokenSource?

It's an implementation detail. I haven't looked at the source, but what I *suspect* is happening is that the `CancellationToken` provided to `ExecuteScalarAsync` is being combined with some internal `CancellationToken` that means "we lost the connection" or something like that. These [linked `CancellationToken`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#listening-to-multiple-tokens-simultaneously) are not equivalent to their source `CancellationToken`s.

This is a usage problem with `CancellationToken`s in general. With linked tokens, it's not always possible to determine *which* cancellation token caused the cancellation. For this reason, I recommend checking your *own* copy of the cancellation token via `catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (cts.IsCancellationRequested)`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);

  try
  {
    await IndirectDelay(10, cts.Token);

    await Task.Delay(timeout + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    await IndirectDelay(10, cts.Token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.CancellationToken == cts.Token); // false
    Console.WriteLine("Our token is canceled.");
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Canceled for some other reason.");
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("General error.");
  }
}

private static async Task IndirectDelay(int timeout, CancellationToken token)
{
  using (var internalCts = new CancellationTokenSource())
  using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, internalCts.Token))
    await Task.Delay(timeout, cts.Token);
}
```

There is a possibility of a race condition where your code would *think* the cancellation happens because of the timeout but really it's because of a connection dropping (or whatever internal logic is going on), but in most cases this doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not even linked: `CancellationTokenSource timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();` in `RunExecuteReaderTds` :(

Comment: @IanMercer: So it completely ignores the token passed in to `ExecuteScalarAsync`? That's not great. Not technically *invalid*, but not very nice to consumers, either.

Comment: It appears to check it's not cancelled before it starts talking to SQL, but then relies on the int timeout value instead. At least that's my quick reading on the source code. Take a look.